# Add existing helper in an extended controller (Redmine Plugin Dev)

Tags: plugins, helper, redmine, redmine-plugins

Can anyone guide me through the right way to **add an existing Helper into an extended controller** which previously did not contain this helper.

For example, I have extended the **timelog_controller.rb** controller in **timelog_controller_patch.rb**. Then, I tried to add the **helper Queries**, which brings some functionality that I want to use in my patch.

If I add the helper in my patch (my timelog extended control), I always get the same error:

Error: **uninitialized constant Rails:: Plugin:: TimelogControllerPatch (NameError)**

Here is an example of how I have done:

```
module TimelogControllerPatch       
    def self.included(base)
        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
        base.class_eval do
          alias_method_chain :index, :filters
        end
    end
    module InstanceMethods
        # Here, I include helper like this (I've noticed how the other controllers do it)
        helper :queries
        include QueriesHelper

        def index_with_filters
            # ...
            # do stuff
            # ...
        end
    end # module
end # module patch
```

However, when I include the same helper in the original controller, everything works fine (of course, this is not the right way).

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `helper` method needs to be called on the controller's class, by putting it into a module it isn't getting run correctly. This will work:

```
module TimelogControllerPatch       
    def self.included(base)
        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
        base.class_eval do
          alias_method_chain :index, :filters
          # 
          # Anything you type in here is just like typing directly in the core
          # source files and will be run when the controller class is loaded.
          # 
          helper :queries
          include QueriesHelper

        end
    end
    module InstanceMethods
        def index_with_filters
            # ...
            # do stuff
            # ...
        end
    end # module
end # module patch
```

Feel free to look at any of my plugins on Github, most of my patches will be in `lib/plugin_name/patches`. I know I have one there that adds a helper but I can't find it right now. https://github.com/edavis10

P.S. don't forget to require your patch too. If it's not in your `lib` directory of your plugin, use the relative path.

Eric Davis

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm! Unfortunately the documentation is pretty sparse and I was not able to find a good solution to this problem. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you don't want to do it with a patch:

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  TimelogController.send(:helper, :queries)
end
```

Comment: This is a good testing solution but, as far a I can see, it is intended only for development purposes. Although, it is a fast and good way to test a proof-of-concept before anything else.